# Eloquent belongs to relationship not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships, lumen

Ok so been trying to figure out how to setup this relationship. Using eloquent Lumen. I have two tables. A Listing table. which contains Consoles. I dont want an emum or plain text in their so I want to extract that into a console table. Console 1, console 2 etc. but i cannot get the relationship to match up for some reason.

```
Listing Table:
id: 1 | console_id: 3
id: 2 | console_id: 4
id: 3 | console_id: 3
id: 4 | console_id: 2

Console Table:
id: 1 | console: Console 1
id: 2 | console: Console 2
id: 3 | console: Console 3
```

Now In my Listing model i have:

```
public function console()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Console');
}
```

The relationship is broken or I am not understanding how this relationship should be tied together...

Answer (score 1):

I think Your class cannot have Console name, cuz Laravel has Console namespace or classes that autoloader will try to load it.

1) Rename Your **Console** class to something like **ConsoleItem**

2) Try to write it like this, type fields exactly (cuz we don't want to change table structure):

```
public function console()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ConsoleItem', 'console_id', 'id');
}
```

3) To get it by calling console using with():

```
$Listings = Listing::with(['console'])->whereConsoleId(3)->get();
foreach($Listings AS $Listing) {
  echo 'Listing: '.$Listing->id.' | Console: '.$Listing->console->console."<br/>";
}
```

If it's still not working, have to analyze why.

So please add contents of files for Your models.

4) clean autoloader cache using cli commands to redump autoloader for composer and clean etc things:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
```

But! It would be better to have Your models to be in app/Models folder, and have code like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Console extends Model
```

so then Your Listing will be like:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Listing extends Model {

  protected $table = 'listing';
  public $timestamps = false;

  public function console() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Console', 'console_id');
  }
}
```

To use them inside controllers:

```
use App\Models\Listing;
```

Check the screenshot: http://joxi.ru/82QWW0f1a4YXrd

Comment: ok. So so adding App\ specifically fixed the relationship issue! However. (I am trying to build an API.) and would love for when I say Listing::all() it would pull the text instead of the number... how does the relationship fire when pulling from the DB?

Comment: Use it like this:  Listing::with(['console'])->get();    but in case of table with thousands of data I recommend You to use it for example like this: Listing::with(['console'])->paginate(50); and make Your API use it more wisely, by sending request like: http://somesite.com/api/listing?page=2   that will tell model automatically to return next 50 elements.

Comment: hmm so $listings = Listing::with(['console'])->get(); dd($listings); still returns the id and not the name...

Comment: check Your relations, to have proper bindings. also try to do var_dump($listings->toArray());  or add me to skype: anarjafarov   I'll help You

Comment: I appreciate all the help man. Can't jump on skype right now. I guess my main question is am I setting up my tables correctly? Is this what I should be doing for a lookup table? or am i going about this all wrong? If i am going down the right path i can fumble around with this a bit more and figure it out. Or is their a different way of going about this.

Comment: Try to play with class names, also check Your relations to be exact, also about dd()  - use var_dump($linstings->toArray());

Comment: so when i loop through with the foreach i can echo out the name... but when i do just the query and dd or var_dump with out doing a foreach it just echos the id...

Comment: trying to build the json object to return to the end user. so rather give them the Name then an id you know.

Comment: You can do looping like this before sending to json: foreach($linstings AS $Listing) {$Listing->contact->contact;}